# FragmentStatePagerAdapter return wrong position but right fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an Activity called MainActivity which has a ViewPager and a TabLayout. The ViewPager has 4 (four) fragments that bound there. I have a problem about (maybe) FragmentStatePagerAdapter

I have my code run

```
public class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    Fragment[] fragments;

    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments = new Fragment[]{
                new FragProfile(),
                new FragScore(),
                new FragMoney(),
                new FragOther()
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int p) {
        Log.w("Fragment", String.valueOf(p));

        switch (p){
            case 0:
                return fragments[0];
            case 1:
                return fragments[1];
            case 2:
                return fragments[2];
            case 3:
                return fragments[3];
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

on first tab, i got this log came out

```
09-10 20:05:29.683 17034-17034/ampersanda.elsys W/Fragment: 0
09-10 20:05:29.684 17034-17034/ampersanda.elsys W/Fragment: 1
```

on second

```
09-10 20:11:03.970 17034-17034/ampersanda.elsys W/Fragment: 2
```

on third

```
09-10 20:11:54.534 17034-17034/ampersanda.elsys W/Fragment: 3
```

but on fourth i got nothing logged, and I back to the third i got this

```
09-10 20:14:07.373 17034-17034/ampersanda.elsys W/Fragment: 1
```

Back to second

```
09-10 20:14:50.241 17034-17034/ampersanda.elsys W/Fragment: 0
```

and I back to the first, i got nothing logged again

my code doesn't run well, but I got Fragment shows like its switch() but not about code inside it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you should use FragmentPagerAdapter because when you use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) the pages may get destroyed, so you will need to recreate them in getItem().

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment.